# How can I change background color with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an array that looks like this:

```
tracker[0] = false
tracker[1] = true
tracker[2] = true
tracker[3] = false
```

and some Div's on my form that look like this:

```
<div id="tracker_0"> </div>
<div id="tracker_1"> </div>
<div id="tracker_2"> </div>
<div id="tracker_3"> </div>
```

What I need is to change the background color of my Div's to red or green depending on the value of my tracker array. This is an array that's a variable size.

Can someone give me some pointers how I could do this using jQuery. I really have little experience with this so I would very much appreciate any help.

thank you,  Marilou

Comment: Just asking for code to solve a problem probably won't prompt much response.  If you have tried something and it is not working then post that and people might help.

Comment: @Hogan. I understand but I'm very new to jQuery so just looking for some hints. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without some code, it's impossible to write working code, but can be something like this:

```
function (){
    var i = 0;
    $("#divWrapper div").each(function(){
        if(tracker[i])
            $(this).css("background-color","red");
        else
            $(this).css("background-color","green");
        i++;
    });
}
```

Where this function is a parameter of your trigger

Edit:

Now that you provided the code, try this:

```
for(i=0; i<tracker.length; i++)
{
    if(tracker[i])
        $("#tracker_"+i).css("background-color","green");
    else
        $("#tracker_"+i).css("background-color","red");
}
```

Comment: My Div's have IDs of tracker_0, tracker_1 etc. Can you explain how I can set this up to do an "each" on each one of these. How can I do the select: "#divWrapper div". Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 5):

```
$.each(tracker, function (i, bool) {
    $('#tracker_'+i).css('backgroundColor', bool ? 'green' : 'red');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I didn't yet try your method but I will try now. I hope u don't mind but I will mark Andre's answer as correct because he answered first. Marilou

Comment: Whatever you like is fine--for the future though, I recommend up-voting the ones you find to be good answers, and only choosing the 'answer' after you get a number of votes in--that will also better highlight what you think to be the best answer for future people visiting the page.